# How to move pixel location but keep brightness the same?

Tags: image, multidimensional-array

My goal here is to simulate the effects of cosmic shear. That is, I (a)create a galaxy and (b)apply shear to the galaxy. Shear indicates the distortion of the galaxies, and is has two components: gamma1 and gamma2. They affect the coordinate in this way:

```
x_sheared = (1 + gamma1) * X + gamma2 * Y
y_sheared = gamma2 * X + (1 - gamma1) * Y
```

To create the galaxy, I generated a number of random points that are centered around the origin. The points also have a "brightness" component determined by their distance to the origin.

```
values = np.exp(-r/r_disk) + f_brightness_ratio*np.exp(-(r/r_bulge)**0.25)
```

Ok, now (X,Y) is moved to the new (x_sheared, y_sheared). However, I also need to make sure that (x_sheared, y_sheared) has the same brightness as in its old location (X,Y). I stuck on this for a long time and could not figure out a solution.

This is how I implemented my idea:

I generated this galaxy by first creating a grid to get the distance to the origin and therefore the values of brightness, then by assigning the brightness values to the mask that I created.

```
def generateGalaxy(num_points, size, r_disk, f_brightness_ratio, r_bulge):

    # generate grid
    x = np.arange(-size/2, size/2)
    y = np.arange(-size/2, size/2)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    r = (X**2 + Y**2)**0.5

    # generate random points
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_points)
    r = np.random.uniform(0, 10, num_points)
    
    #find the x & y coordinates of these randoms points
    x_rand = r * np.cos(theta)
    y_rand = r * np.sin(theta)
    r_rand = np.sqrt(x_rand**2 + y_rand**2)
    
    # assign values based on r_rand
    values = np.exp(-r_rand/r_disk) + f_brightness_ratio*np.exp(-(r_rand/r_bulge)**0.25)
    
    # generate blank image array
    mask_xy = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # generate galaxy image
    mask_xy[y_rand.astype(int) + size//2, x_rand.astype(int) + size//2] = values
    
    return mask_xy, x_rand, y_rand
```

Here is how I originally tried to shear the galaxy.

```
def shearGalaxy(gamma1, gamma2, X, Y, size):
    # set the shear values
    gamma1 = gamma1
    gamma2 = gamma2

    # doing the shear transformation
    x_sheared = (1 + gamma1) * X + gamma2 * Y
    y_sheared = gamma2 * X + (1 - gamma1) * Y
    r_sheared = np.sqrt(x_sheared**2 + y_sheared**2)
    
    # Assign values based on distance
    values_sheared = np.exp(-r_sheared/r_disk) + f_brightness_ratio*np.exp(-(r_sheared/r_bulge)**0.25)
    
    # generate image
    mask_xy_sheared = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask_xy_sheared[y_sheared.astype(int) + size//2, x_sheared.astype(int) + size//2] = values_sheared
    return mask_xy_sheared
```

I later discovered that I was reassigning new brightness values `values_sheared` to the moved pixels and not keeping their original value.

I tried to replace `values_sheared` with `values`(not sure why I did it. I just wanted to see if simply reassigning every pixel with the old value would work, but I am not sure if that would do).

I also tried to work backwards. If I have [x_sheared, y_sheared], and if I know gamma1 & gamma2, then I can certainly work out [X,Y], then compute the brightness at that point using the brightness function, then assign that brightness to the point. However, this method feels stupid because I already have X & Y at my disposition, and I feel that I should somehow directly make use of X & Y, but I currently can't wrap my mind around it.

In addition, I want to know if I can shear the 2D array without knowing the brightness at each coordinate. Here's why it matters to me. I not only have to shear the image I originally generated.  I also have to shear the original image rotated by 45 degrees. I plan to do that using the rotation function in scipy.

```
image_rot = rotate(Galaxy, angle = 45, reshape=False)
```

`Image_rot` gives me a 2D array, so I do know the brightness value of each element of the array. However, I have no idea how to apply shear to that 2D array. Originally, I have a coordinate system I generated by meshgrid to tell me where the new location is. Now, I only have an array.

I tried to get around this by re-using the coordinates from the generateGalaxy function

```
def rotateGalaxy(X, Y, angle):
    x_rot = np.cos(angle) * X + np.sin(angle)* Y
    y_rot = -np.sin(angle) * X + np.cos(angle) * Y
    r_rot = np.sqrt(x_rot**2 + y_rot**2)
    r = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    
    # Assign values based on distance (replace this with your desired function)
    values = np.exp(-r/r_disk) + f_brightness_ratio*np.exp(-(r/r_bulge)**0.25)
    values_rot = np.exp(-r_rot/r_disk) + f_brightness_ratio*np.exp(-(r_rot/r_bulge)**0.25)
    values_rot_normalized = (values_rot - np.min(values_rot)) / (np.max(values_rot)-np.min(values_rot))
    
    # generate image
    mask_xy_rot = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.uint8)
    mask_xy_rot[y_rot.astype(int) + size//2, x_rot.astype(int) + size//2] = values
    
    return mask_xy_rot, x_rot, y_rot
```

Theoretically, this should work. However, when I tried to generate actual images, they seem quite off. Pay close attention to the second galaxy. This is supposed to be the first galaxy rotated counterclockwise by 45 degrees. However, it seems like it has also been distorted somehow. (SG means sheared galaxy)

[image: Rotated Galaxies]

Compare this to the rotated image (the third one) generated by scipy's rotation function. This one makes much more sense (maybe because there is some interpolation going on?)

[image: Rotated Galaxy by scipy]

So I think my attempt to re-use the established coordinate system is not succeeding. Do I regenerate a coordinate system, assign the brightness values of each element to a location, and shear the image? If so, can people tell me how to do that? In addition, is there a way to shear the image without reconstructing a coordinate system? Doing that seems quite complicated and daunting to me right now.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!